# facebook share specific dynamic content according to page

Tags: facebook

I have a websites displaying cars. if user clicks on each car, it will direct to each car info page. I want to share each car content(image,title,description,url).
For ex.if user clicks on car with id 1,share dialog will display content for that car id 1, and if user clicks on car with id 2,share will display content for car id 2. I have googled for solution but have not found it. Below is my code.

```
<head>
<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo 'http://motorcarmyanmar.com';?>" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Buy,Sell,Rent,Or Lease Cars Or Car Accessories In Myanmar" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Car Sales,Car Rentals,Car Accessories Sales" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://motorcarmyanmar.com/pictures/car1.png" />
<meta property="og:image:alt"    content="car picture"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1538657022815637" />
</head>
```

In the beginning of body.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId            : '1538657022815637',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1538657022815637";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

In the car info page.

```
<script>

document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  var title,description,image;
  title=$('#title_fb').val();
  description=$('#description_fb').val();
  image=$('#image_fb').val();
    FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object: {
        'og:url': window.location.href,
        'og:title': title,
        'og:description': description + ' Lakhs',
        'og:image': image,
        'og:image:width':'500',
        'og:image:height':'400'
      }
    })
  },
  function (response) {
  // Action after response
  });


}
</script>
```

With the codes i have given, the dynamic share works. But i want the share image to be bigger not a thumbnail. I read that if share reaches 50 counts,og tags can not be edited. So is there another way to share or is this way right. I saw other website pages sharing dynamic content without creating objects.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Facebookes best practices about pictures sizes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images

Also, you should use a separate URL with a separate `og:url` tag for each share and just `method: 'share'` without other parameters. That `share_open_graph` method is just a workaround.

For example:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo 'http://motorcarmyanmar.com/?id=' . $_GET['id'];?>" />
```

Of course you need to check if the parameter even exists, but it´s just an example.

Comment: how do u do separate url with a separate og:url tag.

Comment: facebook says "If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in the link page post, but the size will be much smaller" but i am using images bigger than that size.

Comment: i don't want to use share_open_graph method.

Comment: do not just take a look at image sizes, but at the aspect ratio too. anyway, separate url means you need to use a parameter in your url, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code i have given, i copied and pasted without really understanding it. I read the documentation too but don't understand that much. For a separate url, can u give me sample code.

Comment: you should ALWAYS try to understand your code, even if you copy it. anyway, i will add the info about a separate url in my answer.

Comment: I have changed the header og:url to  <meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo 'http://motorcarmyanmar.com' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" />. The url is dynamic now. how about image, title, and description to be dynamic. Thanks

Comment: And my share button is <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo 'http://motorcarmyanmar.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode('http://motorcarmyanmar.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>.

Comment: well, you would have to either add all those strings in the url, or store them with a specific id in a database, and only use the id in the url.

Comment: that´s quite broad for stackoverflow, is that really not enough info? i mean, you just use an id as get parameter, you use php code to get the open graph data from your database with that id, and you use the data for the metatags. that really explains everything, it´s very basic php coding.

Comment: I can get open graph data from database with the $_GET id and update metatags. for example, i have a share button in homepage and in car id 1 page. arriving of car id 1 page, meta tag updated. i click share and share shows the old content,then i scrape it, click share in homepage, the share content is updated but click share second time in car id 1 page, the share content is not updated. I am not sure if i am saying it right.

Comment: Arriving on car id 1 page,og tags is updated with car id 1 content and so and on car id 2 page, og tags updated with car id 2 content and so on. After trying again some car pages show right share content and some show default homepage share content.For ex, in car id 1 page, if i click on share, the share content is default homepage content, and in car id 2 page, click on share shows right car id 2 content.

Comment: car id 1 will always have the same og tags then. that´s how it works. you can only use different og tags with different urls, that´s pretty much the main thing to know. if you want different tags, you have to use different urls.

Comment: I have added my code in the answer section below. Can u tell me what is wrong and what i need to add or change. Share url is different for each page, but only title, description and image is sometimes not right for some pages.

Comment: please don´t answers for additional info, put it in your question instead. if the code does not work, please add 2 specific URLs where it does work and where it does not.

Comment: Ok i will put in question next time. if i share each car page, the url is different and correct. for ex. for car id 1 page, the url is motorcarmyanmar.com/id=1,for id 2 page, share url is motorcarmyanmar.com/id=2. what is not correct sometimes is image, title , description shown in share popup. for ex, share popup for car id 1 shows car id 2 image.

Comment: I think it's working now. The problem i think was that data-href of share button has some characters that need to be encoded. for ex. in 'motorcarmyanmar.com/?ca2=details&details=ca2' the '&' has to be encoded to &amp.

Comment: i appreciate your guidiance and time.

Comment: you can also use this format and split the parameter with php: motorcarmyanmar.com?details=title|description|...

Comment: Hi, another issue, the facebook share(v2.8)is working in pc but not in mobile with either data mobile iframe set to true or false. Do you know why.

Answer (score 0):

The url is
  http://www.motorcarmyanmar.com/pages/car_details/ca36?ca36=Details&Details=ca36

```
  <head>
   <?php 
      $title_header="";
      $description_header="";
      $features_header="";
      $image_header="";
      if(isset($_GET['Details']))
    {

     $car_id=$_GET['Details'];
     $car_details= //get from database width $car_id;
     $title_header=$car_details['header'];
     $description_header=$car_details['description'];
     $image_header=$car_details['image'];

    }
    ?>
        <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
        Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
      <meta property="og:url"           content="<?php echo 'http://motorcarmyanmar.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" />
      <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo (!empty($title_header)?$title_header:'Some Buy,Sell,Rent');?>" />

      <meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo (!empty($description_header)?$description_header:'Car Sales,Car Rentals,Car Accessories Sales');?>" />
      <meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo (!empty($image_header)?$image_header:'http://motorcarmyanmar.com/images/icons/car1.jpg');?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:alt"    content="car picture"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1538657022815637" />
    </head>
```

this is what i did. With this code, some pages show right share content(title,description,image),some pages show default homepage share content. But only url is right for each page. Is the code in right direction?